# Assistance with error report needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First off, I apologize for the huge block of code.  This is basically a table that contains 4 select statements (each with a different [Lag_Error]) then unions them all together to create an error report.

My boss is on my about making a change to this (her) code.  I need this error report to capture if (a.region = 'CR' and a.eff_date = '4/1/2016') the [Lag Error] should display 'Lag should be 1' (like from the first select statement).  I was able to accomplish this by using an update statement at the end but she said that I need to go back through the code and make changes to each select statement to do this.

So for any record that has (region CR and eff_date >= 4/1/2016) the [Lag_Error] should read 'Lag Should be 1'

Can any help me with this?  I tried to removed all the comments so I can fit everything and avoid cluster in the code as the comments weren't helpful in following the code.  This may have caused syntax errors.  For that, I apologize.

```
CREATE TABLE [usr].[#AFF_LAG]
(
[OP_NO]         [varchar]  NULL,
[PROV_NO]       [varchar] (12) NOT NULL,
  [AFF_NO]        [varchar] (16) NOT NULL,
  [EFF_DATE]      [datetime] NULL,
  [END_DATE]      [datetime] NULL,
  [LAG]           [int] NULL,
  [Lag_Error]     [varchar] (50) NULL,
  [STATUS]        [varchar] (2) NULL,
  [Prov_Name]     [varchar] (60) NULL,
  [REGION]        [varchar] (2) NULL,
  [SPEC_1]        [varchar] (2) NULL,
  [DESCRIPTION]   [char] (72) NULL,
  [IRS_NO]        [varchar] (10) NULL)
  ON [PRIMARY]

  SELECT DISTINCT a.OP_NO,
               a.PROV_NO,
               a.AFF_NO,
               a.eff_date,
               a.end_Date,
               a.lag,
               'Lag should be 1' AS Lag_Error,
               a.status,
               b.First_Name + ' ' + b.Last_Name AS [Prov_Name],
               Region,
               a.Spec_1,
               [description],
               a.IRS_NO
 INTO #templag2
 FROM amisys.dbo.affiliation a
      INNER JOIN amisys.dbo.provider b ON a.prov_no = b.prov_no
      LEFT OUTER JOIN amisys.dbo.code_detail cd
         ON a.spec_1 = cd.code_no AND prefix = 'sp'
WHERE     a.end_date = '12/31/9999'
      AND a.void = ' '
      AND a.lag <> 1
      AND b.prov_no <> '1000001395'
      AND (   (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'ni')
           OR (a.spec_1 = 'FN' AND region = 'S1')
           OR (a.spec_1 = 'FN' AND region = 'SD')
           OR (a.spec_1 = 'FN' AND region = 'WC')
           OR (a.spec_1 = 'FN' AND region = 'WJ')
           OR     a.prov_no = '100064886'
          OR (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
                AND a.region = 'SI')
          OR (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
                AND a.region = 'wj')
          OR (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region IN ('GC','WC'))
           OR a.irs_no = '274630894'
           OR a.irs_no = '010940346'
           OR (    a.prov_no IN ('1000009816',
                                 '1000011878',
                                 '436211363SC1',
                                 '720204265TE1',
                                 '720914714PE1',
                                 '720975722CE1')
               AND a.region = 'pn')
           OR a.irs_no = '452829073'
           OR     a.prov_no IN ('0001',
                                '0002',
                                '0003',
                                '0004',
                                '0005',
                                '0006',
                                '0007',
                                '0008',
                                '0009',
                                '0010',
                                '0011')
              AND NOT a.prov_no = '100067743')

SELECT DISTINCT a.OP_NO,
               a.PROV_NO,
               a.AFF_NO,
               a.eff_date,
               a.end_Date,
               a.lag,
               'Lag should be 30' AS Lag_Error,
               a.status,
               b.First_Name + ' ' + b.Last_Name AS [Prov_Name],
               Region,
               a.Spec_1,
               [description],
               a.IRS_NO
 INTO #templag3
 FROM amisys.dbo.affiliation a
      INNER JOIN amisys.dbo.provider b ON a.prov_no = b.prov_no
      LEFT OUTER JOIN amisys.dbo.code_detail cd
         ON a.spec_1 = cd.code_no AND prefix = 'sp'
WHERE     a.end_date = '12/31/9999'
      AND a.void = ' '
      AND b.prov_no <> '1000001395'
      AND a.lag <> 30
      AND NOT (   (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'ni')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'ui')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'CI')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'SI')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'wj')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'CA' AND region = 'GC')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'CA' AND region = 'WC')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'OB' AND region = 'WJ'))
      and not  a.prov_no = '100064886'
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region = 'SI')
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region = 'wj')
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region IN ('GC','WC'))
      AND NOT a.prov_no = '720478620ST1'
      AND NOT a.irs_no IN ('201729674',
                           '205432631',
                           '205432782',
                           '271770321',
                           '720276883',
                           '720502505',
                           '721473968',
                           '204670876')
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('1000009816',
                                 '1000011878',
                                 '436211363SC1',
                                 '720204265TE1',
                                 '720914714PE1',
                                 '720975722CE1')
               AND a.region = 'pn')
      AND NOT a.irs_no = '452829073'
      AND NOT a.prov_no IN ('0001',
                            '0002',
                            '0003',
                            '0004',
                            '0005',
                            '0006',
                            '0007',
                            '0008',
                            '0009',
                            '0010',
                            '0011')
      AND NOT a.prov_no = '100067743'



SELECT DISTINCT a.OP_NO,
               a.PROV_NO,
               a.AFF_NO,
               a.eff_date,
               a.end_Date,
               a.lag,
               'Lag should be 25' AS Lag_Error,
               a.status,
               b.First_Name + ' ' + b.Last_Name AS [Prov_Name],
               Region,
               a.Spec_1,
               [description],
               a.IRS_NO
 INTO #templag4
 FROM amisys.dbo.affiliation a
      INNER JOIN amisys.dbo.provider b ON a.prov_no = b.prov_no
      LEFT OUTER JOIN amisys.dbo.code_detail cd
         ON a.spec_1 = cd.code_no AND prefix = 'sp'
WHERE     a.end_date = '12/31/9999'
      AND a.void = ' '
      AND a.lag <> 25
      AND a.prov_no = '720478620ST1'
      AND NOT a.prov_no = '100067743'

SELECT DISTINCT a.OP_NO,
               a.PROV_NO,
               a.AFF_NO,
               a.eff_date,
               a.end_Date,
               a.lag,
               'Lag should be 21' AS Lag_Error,
               a.status,
               b.First_Name + ' ' + b.Last_Name AS [Prov_Name],
               Region,
               a.Spec_1,
               [description],
               a.IRS_NO
 INTO #templag5
 FROM amisys.dbo.affiliation a
      INNER JOIN amisys.dbo.provider b ON a.prov_no = b.prov_no
      LEFT OUTER JOIN amisys.dbo.code_detail cd
         ON a.spec_1 = cd.code_no AND prefix = 'sp'
WHERE     a.end_date = '12/31/9999'
      AND a.void = ' '
      AND b.prov_no <> '1000001395'
      AND a.lag <> '21'
      AND (   a.irs_no IN ('201729674',
                           '205432631',
                           '205432782',
                           '271770321',
                           '720276883',
                           '720502505',
                           '721473968',
                           '204670876')
           OR b.prov_no = '0012')
      AND NOT (   (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'ni')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'ui')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'ca' AND region = 'CI')
               OR (a.spec_1 = 'FN' AND region = 'WJ'))
     and not  a.prov_no = '100064886'
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region = 'SI')
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region = 'WJ')
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('100070539', '721313430ST1')
               AND a.region IN ('GC','WC'))
      AND NOT a.prov_no = '720478620ST1'
      AND NOT a.irs_no = '274630894'
      AND NOT a.irs_no = '010940346'
      AND NOT (    a.prov_no IN ('1000009816',
                                 '1000011878',
                                 '436211363SC1',
                                 '720204265TE1',
                                 '720914714PE1',
                                 '720975722CE1')
               AND a.region = 'pn')
      AND NOT a.irs_no = '452829073'
      AND NOT a.prov_no IN ('0001',
                            '0002',
                            '0003',
                            '0004',
                            '0005',
                            '0006',
                            '0007',
                            '0008',
                            '0009',
                            '0010',
                            '0011')
      AND NOT a.prov_no = '100067743'


INSERT INTO #AFF_LAG
  SELECT * FROM #templag2
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM #templag3
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM #templag4
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM #templag5



SELECT service_No,
      CLAIM_NO,
      Member_No,
      P.Aff_No AS SVC_AFF_NO,
      p.paid,
      Amt_Charge,
      Amt_Allow_P,
      Amt_Copay,
      Amt_Coin,
      Amt_Risk,
      Amt_pay,
      Count_1,
      Ex_1,
      Location,
      Procedure_1,
      Modifier_1,
      P.Eff_Date AS CLM_EFF_DATE,
      Paid_Date,
      A.[OP_NO],
      A.[PROV_NO],
      A.[AFF_NO],
      A.[eff_DATE],
      A.[END_DATE],
      A.[LAG],
      A.[Lag_Error],
      A.[STATUS],
      A.[Prov_Name],
      A.[REGION],
      A.[SPEC_1],
      A.[DESCRIPTION],
      A.[IRS_NO]
 FROM #aff_lag AS A
      LEFT OUTER JOIN AMISYS.dbo.service AS P
         ON A.AFF_NO = P.AFF_NO AND p.paid IN ('NN', '*N')
GROUP BY service_No,
        CLAIM_NO,
        Member_No,
        P.Aff_No,
        P.Paid,
        Amt_Charge,
        Amt_Allow_P,
        Amt_Copay,
        Amt_Coin,
        Amt_Risk,
        Amt_pay,
        Count_1,
        Ex_1,
        Location,
        Procedure_1,
        Modifier_1,
        P.Eff_Date,
        Paid_Date,
        A.[OP_NO],
        A.[PROV_NO],
        A.[AFF_NO],
        A.[eff_DATE],
        A.[END_DATE],
        A.[LAG],
        A.[Lag_Error],
        A.[STATUS],
        A.[Prov_Name],
        A.[REGION],
        A.[SPEC_1],
        A.[DESCRIPTION],
        A.[IRS_NO]

DROP TABLE #AFF_LAG
DROP TABLE #templag2
DROP TABLE #templag3
DROP TABLE #templag4
DROP TABLE #templag5
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but this is an `OR` nightmare... have you considered creating a temp table to `JOIN` to rather than a mile-long `OR` list?

Comment: The 'OR' can be ignored for the most part.  The purpose is to add the logic '(region = 'CR' and EFF_DATE >= '4/1/2016')' should be [Lag_Error] = 'Lag Should be 1'

Comment: Not sure i got right, but why not `SELECT .. CASE WHEN region ='CR' and eff_date >= '4/1/2016' THEN  'Lag should be 1' ELSE ... END AS  [Lag Error]` ?

Comment: Please, suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you talk to your boss and advocate strongly to refactor this, however, it sounds like she may not be receptive to the idea.

If you must change all the selects, then change the `WHERE` in the first statement (Lag should be 1) to check for the new requirement **or** all the other requirements. This will take care of *any* row where `region = 'CR' and eff_date >= 4/1/2016`:

```
WHERE (region = 'CR' and eff_date >= '4/1/2016')
      OR
      (
      ...   --Rest of where clause goes here
      )
```

Change the other selects to ignore rows that meet the new requirement, since the first statement will have returned all of them:

```
WHERE NOT(region = 'CR' and eff_date >= '4/1/2016')
      AND ...    --Rest of where clause goes here
```